# MongoDB aggregation: Project separate document fields into a single array field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a document like this:

```
{fax: '8135551234', cellphone: '8134441234'}
```

Is there a way to project (without a group stage) this document into this:

```
{
    phones: [{
        type: 'fax',
        number: '8135551234'
    }, {
        type: 'cellphone',
        number: '8134441234'
    }]
}
```

I could probably use a group stage operator for this, but I'd rather not if there's any other way, because my query also projects several other fields, all of which would require a `$first` just for the group stage.

Hope that's clear. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without a `$group` stage, it is not possible.

Comment: On the off-chance it inspires an alternative solution, why are you trying to group the `fax` and `cellphone` fields into an array like that?

Comment: The reason for matching it like that, is to format the documents from a large collection (npi database) into the model my app uses, where you can have an arbitrary number of phones of any type, as opposed to specific fields for each type of phone.

Comment: BTW, having the document formatted like this isn't a strict requirement, and there are ways around it in database (group stage) or in code (post  processing the result in the app). I just wonder if there is way to do this in database outside of a group stage or not, for future reference.

Comment: There isn't, sadly. The `$project` stage doesn't project field values into array values very well, see [SERVER-8141](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8141).

Comment: @wdberkeley Thanks! That answers my question, and gives me a place to look for future developments. Please add it as an answer

Comment: @wdberkeley Of course it can be done. You just need to think about it. `$map` transforms arrays

Comment: No, the hitch was that the field names are varying. You had to construct an array of all possible field names when there could be an arbitrary number of different names for different types of phones. See the third comment.

Comment: Actually, @NeilLunn is correct, my comment was that there could be an arbitrary number of phones, but the possible phone types are a limited choice. Thank you both for your comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MongoDB 2.6 Introduces the the [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator which is an array transformation operator which can be used to do exactly this:

```js
db.phones.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "phones": { "$map": {
            "input": { "$literal": ["fax","cellphone"] },
            "as": "el",
            "in": {
                "type": "$$el",
                "number": { "$cond": [
                     { "$eq": [ "$$el", "fax" ] },
                     "$fax",
                     "$cellphone"
                 ]}
             }
        }}
    }}
])
```

So your document now looks exactly like you want. The trick of course to to create a new array with members "fax" and "cellphone", then transform that array with the new document fields by matching those values.

Of course you can also do this in earlier versions using [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) in a similar fashion, but just not as efficiently:

```js
db.phones.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "type": { "$const": ["fax","cellphone"] },
        "fax": 1,
        "cellphone": 1
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$type" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "_id",
        "phones": { "$push": { 
            "type": "$type",
            "number": { "$cond": [
                { "$eq": [ "$type", "fax" ] },
                "$fax",
                "$cellphone"
            ]}
        }}
    }}
])
```

Of course it can be argued that unless you are doing some sort of aggregation then you may as well just post process the collection results in code. But this is an alternate way to do that.

Comment: Awesome. Not sure how I didn't think of this, I knew about the `$map` operator, but didn't think of passing it an array of the possible phone types :)